# PHP delete current 'note' not working

Tags: php

I'm generating a delete button for each 'note' the user creates. However, no matter which delete you click, its deleting the most recently saved note, not the one corresponding to the note. I assume that something is wrong with my hidden field 'deleteID'.

```
<!-- connections.php connects to the database -->
<?php require 'connections.php'; ?>

<!-- check to make sure the user is logged in,
     if not then redirect them to login.php -->
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){ 
} else {
    header('Location: Login.php');
    die();
}?>

<!-- $result is a query containing all the notes
     of the current user -->
<?php $UserID = $_SESSION["UserID"];
      $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE UserID = '$UserID'");    
?>

<!-- when you click 'save' upload the new note 
     to the database and refresh the page.
     when you click 'delete' remote the note
     that goes with that button from the database -->
<?php  if(isset($_POST['save'])) {

        session_start();
        $note = $_POST['note'];
        $UserID = ($_SESSION["UserID"]);

        $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO notes (UserID, note)Values('{$UserID}','{$note}')");

        header('Location: Account.php');

    } else if (isset($_POST['delete'])){
        $deleteID = $_POST['deleteID'];

        $sql = $con->query("DELETE FROM notes WHERE noteID = '$deleteID'");

        header('Location: Account.php');

    } else if (isset($_POST['edit'])){


}?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My Account</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1 class="titleAct">Welcome</h1> 

        <form action="" method="post" name="notesubmit" id="notesubmit">

                <div>
                    <textarea name="note" cols="50" rows="4" form="notesubmit" id="noteinput">New Note
                    </textarea>   
                </div>

                    <input name="save"  type="submit" class="button" id="save" value="Save">  

            <!-- Whenever a note is saved, print out the
                 note with timestamp followed by the edit
                 and delete buttons for each note -->
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
                <?php $note = $row['note'];?>
                <?php $date = $row['time'];?>
                <?php $noteID = $row['noteID'];?>

        <div id="note">
            <p class="note"><?php echo $date; ?></br> ---------------- </br><?php echo $note; ?> </p>
        </div>


                <input name="deleteID" type="hidden" id="hidden<?php echo $noteID;?>" value="<?php echo $noteID; ?>">
                <input name="delete"  type="submit" class="button" value="Delete">

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </form>

        <div>
            <a class="link" href="Logout.php">Logout</a>
            <div>
            <a class="link" href="Deactivate.php">Deactivate My Account</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inspect your code with browser inspector, is there different value of ID in all your hidden delete input ?

Comment: Yes, I did and all deleteIDs have different values.

Comment: Try debugging `$deleteID` before the $sql request with this : `echo $deleteID; die('here');` If it's the same ID no matter the choice you make then, there's is a problem in your form

Comment: Okay, so when I do that it is pulling the latest note instead of the note corresponding to the button. So as you said a mistake in my form probably?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking its not the delete at all - but the div with the note in it - each has the same id since they are in the while loop and therefore every note div has the id of "note"

```
<div id="note">
```

its should be

```
   <div id="note<?php echo $noteID;?>";
```

Comment: also - not sure if its an issue 0 but the </br>'s seem incorrect. if they are line breaks the should be <br/>

Comment: That doesn't effect which note is deleted. The div is the same for css purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be in the name of the input. Should be the same as the value you set in the ID part.

Like this :

```
<input name="hidden<?php echo $noteID;?>" type="hidden" id="hidden<?php echo $noteID;?>" value="<?php echo $noteID; ?>">
```

Otherwise, all your inputs have the same name, and it takes the last one to do the query.

**EDIT**

Put the name of the value you want to delete directly in the submit button like this :

```
<input name="delete-<?php echo $noteID;?>"  type="submit" class="button" value="Delete">
```

Then you can get the value in `$_POST` array and `explode()` the value on `-` separator to get the ID value.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But then how do I discern what my $deleteID will equal to in my else if?

Comment: With a foreach of $_POST : `foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ }`, $key will give you for example "delete-48", then you can test the key with this for instance : `if(strstr($key,'delete') { // your code } `

Answer (score 0):

you also have multiple submit inputs for the one form - one to trigger the save and one each for each echo-ed delete note, so triggering the delete submit function is going to first trigger the save submit - therefore $_POST['save'] will be acted on before the $_POST['delete']. This could be the issue behind the action of altering the last input note rather than the one that was the trigger action.

I would suggest splitting off the add note function to a different form than the delete note functions. You can have the same if else logic and this should work as expected in the new version since you are actually posting the information you are expecting to.